# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : PFFile]' with an index of type 'String!'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have declared a global variable 'var recipes = String: PFFile'.

On parse.com, I created a column called "recipe" of type File and i have uploaded .txt files that contain the recipes.

I am trying to load the contents of the .txt files from parse to a UITextView.

I have tried many things and this is what I have:

```
let recipeFile = object["recipe"] as! PFFile
recipeFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (recipeData, error) -> Void in


     if error == nil {

         let data = recipeData

     } else {

         print(error)

     }

     if let data = recipeData {

         self.recipes[appetizerName] = PFFile(data: data)

         // gives error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : PFFile]' with an index of type 'String!'
         //   self.myTextView.text = self.recipes[self.valuePassed]

     }

 })
```

Comment: Where is `appetizerName` defined?

Comment: @Paulw11 In the view controller, i am displaying the image, name of recipe and the recipe.  appetizerName is defined in the code above for the 'name of the recipe' as: "let appetizerName = object.objectForKey("appetizer") as! String"  "self.name.text = self.valuePassed"